# How can I optimise my neo4j cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please check my Cypher below, I am getting result with the query below() with low records but as records increases it take a long time about 1601152 ms: 
i found suggestion to add `USING INDEX` and and I apply the `USING INDEX` in query.

```
PROFILE MATCH (m:Movie)-[:IN_APP]->(a:App {app_id: '1'})<-[:USER_IN]-(p:Person)-[:WATCHED]->(ma:Movie)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag)<-[:HAS_TAG]-(mb:Movie)-[:IN_APP]->(a) 
USING INDEX a:App(app_id) WHERE p.person_id= '1' 
    AND NOT (p:Person)-[:WATCHED]-(mb) 
RETURN DISTINCT(mb.movie_id) , mb.title, mb.imdb_rating, mb.runtime, mb.award, mb.watch_count, COLLECT(DISTINCT(t.tag_id)) as Tag, count(DISTINCT(t.tag_id)) as matched_tags 
ORDER BY matched_tags DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 50
```

Can you help me out what can I do?

I am trying to find 100 movies for recommendation on basis of tags, as 100 movies which I do not watch and match with tags of Movies I watched.

Answer (score 2):

The following query may work better for you [assuming you have indexes on both `:App(app_id)` and `:Person(person_id)`]. *By the way, I presumed that in your query the identifier `ma` should have been `m` (or vice versa).*

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[:IN_APP]->(a:App {app_id: '1'})<-[:USER_IN]-(p:Person {person_id: '1'})-[:WATCHED]->(m)
WITH a, p, COLLECT(m) AS movies
UNWIND movies AS movie
MATCH (movie)-[:HAS_TAG]->(t)<-[:HAS_TAG]-(mb:Movie)-[:IN_APP]->(a)
WHERE NOT mb IN movies
WITH DISTINCT mb, t
RETURN mb.movie_id, mb.title, mb.imdb_rating, mb.runtime, mb.award, mb.watch_count, COLLECT(t.tag_id) as Tag, COUNT(t.tag_id) as matched_tags
ORDER BY matched_tags DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 50;
```

If you `PROFILE` this query, you should see that it performs `NodeIndexSeek` operations (instead of the much slower `NodeByLabelScan`) to quickly execute the first `MATCH`. The query also collects all the `movies` watched by the specified person and uses that collection later to speed up the `WHERE` clause (which no longer needs hit the DB). In addition, the query removed some labels from some of the node patterns (where doing so seemed likely to be unambiguous) to speed up processing further.